# Want to capture host metrics for 60 min in every 3 sec through nmon

Tags: linux, performance

I want to run **nmon** for **60 min** which will collect the host metrics in every **3sec**. And to achieve this I run the below query on my host,

```
nmon -ft -s 3 -c 60 /home/Documents/nmon
```

When I analyze the result, it is not capturing every 3-sec interval (to verify I just took a 1min snap). Please refer the screenshot attached below.

[image]

Also, I tried to search the process (nmon) in the process list, unable to find it through ps command.

```
ps -aef | grep nmon
ps -aux | grep nmon
```

Comment: does the directory `/home/Documents/` exist? this works perfectly for me, logging the data into file called `[my_user]_date_time.nmon`

Comment: Yeah, I verified it. The directory exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to do some math here before this few note on the arguments provided.

```
-c  Specifies the number snapshots that must be taken by the command. The default value is 10000000.
```

Your requirement is **"60 min which will collect the host metrics in every 3sec."**

So 1 min would be contained 20count and for 60min it should be 1200. This should be compensate your ask,

```
nmon -ft -s 3 -c 1200 /opt/data/nmondata
```